# python .find() by font awesome icon

Tags: python

I need to get the href from `<a>` by icon, using `.find()`.

This is my class:

```
<li class="item">
                            <a class="link" href="?page=2">
                                <i class="fas fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

And I want to print the url if `fa-angle-right` exist and current page.

Trying with this code:

```
def next_page(self, current_page: HTML):
    next_page_href = current_page.find('i',{"class": "fa-angle-right"}, first=True)
    next_page_html = self._get_url_content('{url}{next_page}'.format(
        url=self.url,
        next_page=next_page_href.attrs['href']
    ))

    if current_page.url == next_page_html.url:
        return None

    return next_page_html
```

Someone to help, where is my mistake.

Comment: Why do you think that there is a mistake?

Comment: cuz not print the url...

Comment: There is no `print` in this code and `url` is not defined.  Make a [mcve] that when copied and run *without changes* reproduces the problem.

Comment: but not return the next_page_html